# Migration ionic 5 to ionic 7: Where is @ionic-native/screenshot/ngx?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-native, ionic7

I am migrating a ionic5 project to ionic 7. I am missing the library @ionic-native/screenshot/ngx
Do you know where I can find the plugin? Thanks a lot.

I searched in https://ionicframework.com/docs/native but it seems that there is no screenshot plugin. How can I replace it?

Comment: Please read about what is on topic in the [help/on-topic]. Questions asking us to find or recommend an off-site resource, like a plugin, are explicitly _off topic_ as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Answer (score 0):

@ionic/native has been converted to [awesome cordova plugins](https://danielsogl.gitbook.io/awesome-cordova-plugins).

You need to convert all your old plugins to the new version.